# how to convert pandas data with strings as rows to each words in that strings as rows in same column?

Tags: python, string, pandas

how to convert pandas data with strings as rows to each words in that strings as rows in same column?

Eg:

```
0 I love python
1 I hate programming
```

to

```
0 I
1 love
2 python 
3 I
4 hate
5 programming
```

Answer (score 4):

Join the series with space and split again:

```
pd.Series(' '.join(s).split())

0              I
1           love
2         python
3              I
4           hate
5    programming
dtype: object
```

Alternatively, you can use `pd.Series.str.cat` to accomplish the join

```
pd.Series(s.str.cat(sep=' ').split())

0              I
1           love
2         python
3              I
4           hate
5    programming
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

Split on space and then call `stack`:

```
s.str.split(expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True)

0              I
1           love
2         python
3              I
4           hate
5    programming
dtype: object
```

Offering another option with `np.chararray.split`/`str.split` + `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
pd.Series(list(
     chain.from_iterable(np.chararray.split(s.values.astype(str), sep=' ').tolist())
))
```

Or,

```
pd.Series(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s.str.split().tolist()))
```

```
0              I
1           love
2         python
3              I
4           hate
5    programming
dtype: object
```

---

**Timings**
Thought this would be fun to time, there are quite a plethora of choices. First, the setup:

```
s = pd.concat([s] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
```

Now, the timings:

```
# in this answer

%timeit s.str.split(expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
87.6 ms ± 2.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
pd.Series(list(
     chain.from_iterable(np.chararray.split(s.values.astype(str), sep=' ').tolist())
))

38.1 ms ± 342 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit pd.Series(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(s.str.split().tolist()))
24.9 ms ± 124 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
# jezrael

%timeit np.concatenate(s.str.split().values)
88.2 ms ± 1.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit pd.Series([item for sublist in s.str.split() for item in sublist])
27.5 ms ± 590 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
# piRSquared

%timeit pd.Series(' '.join(s).split())
7.33 ms ± 234 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit pd.Series(s.str.cat(sep=' ').split())
8.93 ms ± 106 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

piR's answer is the clear winner! Python's string operations are super fast here because they run at C speed.

Answer (score 3):

First [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values to `list`s and then flatenning:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.concatenate(df['col'].str.split().values)})
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [item for sublist in df['col'].str.split() for item in sublist]})

print (df)
           col
0            I
1         love
2       python
3            I
4         hate
5  programming
```